# db2 - How to query library (database) with period in name with sql?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

Have an as400 library (database) named VSTAX.D (SYSTEM_TABLE_SCHEMA: "VSTAX.D").

When I try to query it using php odbc_connect I get the error:

```
select RTGST from VSTAX.D.VTSREG

[IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]
SQL0950 - Relational database VSTAX not in relational database directory.
```

I believe this is because of the period in the library name. Is there a way to escape this in the sql statement?

Comment: Maybe using double quotes? Names with special characters must be quoted in DB2: `select RTGST from "VSTAX.D.VTSREG"`

Comment: I think it is then treated like simply the table name when you do that... [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0204 - VSTAX.D.VTSREG in CGPUBLIC type *FILE not found.

Comment: What happens with   "VSTAX.D"."VTSREG" ?  (i.e. separate double quotes pairs around the schema-name, and table name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quotes will handle this for you so this should work:

```
select RTGST from "VSTAX.D".VTSREG
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... yes, that did work for me. Thank you.